# Converting Scientific Notation to Float/Integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC(Doesn't matter for this problem) and am looking for idea as am having problem with below scenario

I am having a sample class

```
Class Mountains
{
    float distance;
    int Altitude;
}
```

In UI if user types long integer(`11111111111111111111111111111`) or floating number(`1111.22232343243546`) in Textbox values are converted to scientific notation(`1.11111111111111E+55`) when it reached C#(Controller) and assigned to distance and Altitude. But before saving to DB or for some other internal logics. I don't want the scientific notation and would be happy to leave that as long values.

I can change at individual properties with

```
decimal.Parse("1.11111111111111E+55", NumberStyles.Float);
```

Is there a way I can change the default behaviour? and I need to implement at **application level across pages** so what is the best possible solution I can use rather typing at each properties for float and integer?

**Extension method** is what comes to my mind even that I need to call that method for each property and assign it to object again rather than directly passing the object to the next layer ?

Is there a better Place I can achieve this in .NET?

Comment: "when it reaches controller it is converted to scientific notation" - what do you mean by that? Surely it's just a `float`. And if you want it as a `long`, that means the values you've shown us wouldn't even be valid. I'm afraid it's fairly unclear what the situation is here - but make sure you're not getting confused between the *value* of a `float` (which isn't in any format) and a *textual representation* of a `float`, e.g. in a debugger.

Comment: @JonSkeet So should i use some other DataType for long Values  rather than float ?

Comment: Well `long` is a 64-bit integer type. `float` is a 32-bit binary floating point type. They're completely different types - use the right one for whatever you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: `Is there a way I can change the default behaviour?` is a terrible idea.  Anyone who uses your assembly or new programmers will have no idea why a method that has always worked one way, now works another way.  Instead write your own extension method `ToScientificFloat()` and/or `ToScientificInt()`.  Now when people see this method, they instantly know it's doing something that is not default behavior.